# Screen resolution handling

Tags: android, libgdx, screen, resolution

So the fact that my textboxes are ending up in different places depending on which device I run it on is tearing my soul apart. I really cant fix this.

This is the code:
I know it is a mess right now, since I was playing around with the viewport API that Libgdx provides. But it didn´t help anything. 
To describe what the last thing i tried was that I set the X & Y coordinates for the textboxes to be final and have no unit assign to it. Although, when running on my tablet the textboxes as always ends up totally away from where they were set on my phone.

```
public class StoneScreen implements Screen, purchaseInterface {

OrthographicCamera camera;
Viewport view;
final TombStone game;
purchaseInterface pInt;
//Textures and art.
public Texture background, sdStone, arrowBack, stone_3, flowerTex, flowerTex_2, flowerTemp;
public Sprite backgrounds;

//TextField´s stuff
private Stage stage;
private Skin skin;
ImageButton btnArrow, btnFB;


Image stoneImage, flowerImage, flowerImage_2, flowerImageTemp;

private static int counter= 1;


private static final float screenWidth = 1000;
private static final float screenHeight = 1500;

private  final float textX = 200;
private  final float textY = 700;

private  final float textAreaX = 200;
private  final float textAreaY = 400;

private  final int textWidth = 350;
private  final int textHeight = 100;

private final float stoneWidth = 600;
private final float stoneHeight = 800;




public StoneScreen(TombStone gam)    {
    this.game = gam;
    this.pInt = game.pi;
    //Set´s the current device´s height and width into a float for easier usage


   //Set´s the tombstones height and width


   //viewport = new FitViewport(camera, screenWidth, screenHeight)

    float aspectRatio = (float) Gdx.graphics.getHeight() / (float)Gdx.graphics.getWidth();

    camera = new OrthographicCamera();
    camera.setToOrtho(false, screenWidth, screenHeight);




    game.assets.load();
    loadStandard();


    stoneImage = new Image(sdStone);
    flowerImage = new Image(flowerTemp);
    //flowerImageTemp = new Image(flowerTemp);
    //flowerImage_2 = new Image(flowerTex_2);


}

public void loadStandard(){
    background = game.assets.background;
    sdStone = game.assets.sdStone;
    stone_3 = game.assets.stone3;
    flowerTex = game.assets.flowerTexture;
    flowerTemp = game.assets.flowerTemp;
    //backgrounds = Assets.backgrounds;
}




@Override
public void render(float delta) {
    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0, 0, 0.2f,1);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);





    camera.update();
    game.batch.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined);


    game.batch.begin();
    Gdx.app.log("X", "FPS:" + Gdx.graphics.getFramesPerSecond());



    game.batch.draw(background,0,0);

    //game.batch.draw(sdStone, 160, 190, screenWidth * 0.60f, screenHeight * 0.60f);

    stoneImage.setBounds(180, 190, stoneWidth, stoneHeight);
    stoneImage.draw(game.batch, 2);


    flowerImage.setBounds(300, 50, screenWidth * 0.65f, screenHeight * 0.30f);
    flowerImage.draw(game.batch, 2);

    //SpriteBatch batcher = (SpriteBatch)stage.getBatch();


    game.batch.end();

    stage.act(Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime());
    stage.draw();


}



@Override
public void resize(int width, int height) {

    //float aspectRatio = (float) height / (float) width;
    //camera  = new OrthographicCamera(screenWidth, screenHeight * aspectRatio);
    //view.update(width, height);

    camera.update();
}

@Override
public void show() {




    //Generates the new font
    FreeTypeFontGenerator generator = new FreeTypeFontGenerator(Gdx.files.internal("AcademyEngraved.ttf"));
    FreeTypeFontParameter parameter = new FreeTypeFontParameter();
    parameter.size = 40;
    BitmapFont textFont = generator.generateFont(parameter);
    generator.dispose(); //Avoiding memory leaks.




Preferences prefs = Gdx.app.getPreferences("preferences");

Skin skin = new Skin();
Skin textSkin = new Skin();

stage = new Stage();
Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(stage);
//Sets skin
skin = new Skin(Gdx.files.internal("uiskin.json"));
//Sets a color to the new font
Color fontcolor = Color.BLACK;

//Sets a new font to the textare n the textfield
TextFieldStyle textstyle = new TextFieldStyle();
textstyle.font = textFont;
textstyle.fontColor = fontcolor;


final TextArea textArea = new TextArea(prefs.getString("textArea", "Enter text:"), textstyle);
textArea.setX(textAreaX);
textArea.setY(textAreaY);
textArea.setWidth(textWidth);
textArea.setHeight(textHeight);
textArea.setMaxLength(30);
textArea.setZIndex(5);


final TextField textField = new TextField(prefs.getString("textField", "Enter name:"), textstyle);

    textField.setX(textX);
    textField.setY(textY);
    textField.setMaxLength(20);
    textField.setWidth(textWidth);
    textField.setHeight(textHeight);







    //String text = Gdx.app.getPreferences("prefs").getString("text", "Default text if missimg");
    //TextField textField = new TextField(text, skin);

    //Backbutton 
            ImageButtonStyle styleTwo = new ImageButtonStyle();
            //ImageButtonStyle styleFB = new ImageButtonStyle();
            TextureRegionDrawable arrowImage = new TextureRegionDrawable(new TextureRegion(new Texture("pil.png")));
            TextureRegionDrawable arrowImageDown = new TextureRegionDrawable(new TextureRegion(new Texture("pilD.png")));

            //TextureRegionDrawable fbImage = new TextureRegionDrawable(new TextureRegion(new Texture("fb.png")));
            //TextureRegionDrawable fbImageDown = new TextureRegionDrawable(new TextureRegion(new Texture("fbDown.png")));
            styleTwo.up = skin.newDrawable(skin.newDrawable(arrowImage));
            styleTwo.down = skin.newDrawable(skin.newDrawable(arrowImageDown));

            styleTwo.pressedOffsetX = -1;
            styleTwo.pressedOffsetY = -1;

            //styleFB.up = skin.newDrawable(skin.newDrawable(fbImage));
            //styleFB.down = skin.newDrawable(skin.newDrawable(fbImageDown));

            //styleFB.pressedOffsetX = -1;
            //styleFB.pressedOffsetY = -1;


            /*Object[] dropMenu = new Object[2];
            dropMenu[0] = new Label("this iaios", skin);

            final SelectBox<Object> sb = new SelectBox<Object>(skin);
            sb.setItems(dropMenu);


            Table table = new Table();
            table.setFillParent(true);
            table.setPosition(0, 800);

            table.add(sb);*/


            //Back button
    btnArrow = new ImageButton(styleTwo);
    //btnFB = new ImageButton(styleFB);


    btnArrow.setSize(150, 150);
    btnArrow.setPosition(50, 10);

    //btnFB.setSize(100, 100);
    //btnFB.setPosition(800, 10);

    stage.addActor(textArea);
    stage.addActor(textField);
    stage.addActor(btnArrow);
    //stage.addActor(table);









    //Backbutton takes us back to mainmenu
            btnArrow.addListener(new ChangeListener() {

                @Override
                public void changed(ChangeEvent event, Actor actor) {
                    game.setScreen(new MainScreen(game));


                    //Saves the entered text.

                    Preferences prefs = Gdx.app.getPreferences("preferences");
                    prefs.putString("textField", textField.getText());
                    prefs.putString("textArea", textArea.getText());
                    prefs.flush();


                }


            });

}

@Override
public void hide() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void pause() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void resume() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void dispose() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

public void changeStone1() {
    //sdStone.dispose();
    stoneImage.setDrawable(new SpriteDrawable(new Sprite(stone_3)));

    camera.update();
}


private static void saveScreenshot() {
    try{
        FileHandle fh;
        do{
            fh = new FileHandle("screenshot" + counter++ + ".png");
        }while(fh.exists());
        Pixmap pixmap = getScreenshot(0, 0, Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight(), false);
        PixmapIO.writePNG(fh, pixmap);
        pixmap.dispose();
    }catch(Exception e) {

    }

}

private static Pixmap getScreenshot(int x, int y, int w, int h, boolean yDown){
    final Pixmap pixmap = ScreenUtils.getFrameBufferPixmap(x, y, w, h);

    if(yDown) {
        ByteBuffer pixels = pixmap.getPixels();
        int numBytes = w * h * 4;
        byte[] lines = new byte[numBytes];
        int numBytesPerLine = w * 4;
        for (int i = 0; i < h; i++) {
            pixels.position((h - i - 1) * numBytesPerLine);
            pixels.get(lines, i * numBytesPerLine, numBytesPerLine);
        }
        pixels.clear();
        pixels.put(lines);
    }
    return pixmap;
}

@Override
public void applyTombstone() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void applyTombstone1() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void applyTombstone2() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void applyFlower() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    flowerImage.setDrawable(new SpriteDrawable(new Sprite(flowerTex)));

    camera.update();
}

@Override
public void applyFlower1() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void applyLight() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void processPurchases() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void changeStone() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    stoneImage.setDrawable(new SpriteDrawable(new Sprite(stone_3)));

    camera.update();
}
```

}

Comment: So you should read about supporting multiple screen resolutions.

Comment: Use an ExtendViewport for your stage. If that Viewport is making things tricky for the rest of your game, use two Stages, one of which is only for UI. You can use an InputMultiplexor to get input from both stages. The UI stuff can be easily adapted to various screen sizes if you put all of it into a Table that's set to fill parent.

Comment: Oh okey. So I can assign my stage to an viewport? And how would that be done? I´ve never done an app like this before.

Comment: Umm...stage.setViewport(viewport);  :)

Comment: If your problem has been solved, please post the solution and mark it as accepted. It would save time of many people reading it anyways. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So here´s the solution:

```
@Override
public void resize(int width, int height) {


    stageText.getViewport().update(width, height, true);

}
```

I simply made the textField I wanted to be positioned to a seperate Stage so that the other elements in my app wouldn´t be affected.